# Is it possible at single product page of woocommerce to display more than one featured images?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am a new woocommerce user and want to add more than one feature image on to a single product page with long and short descriptions and with an add to cart button, without an related product.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Featured image**
The Product Image is the main image for your product. It is displayed in your product loops (i.e., product categories, up-sells, related products, etc.)

**Product galleries**
Product galleries display all images attached to a product through the Product Gallery meta box.

You can create a product gallery using the same method as adding a featured image, but using the Product Gallery meta box.

Follow the Documentation
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/adding-product-images-and-galleries/